# How to achieve the functionality of UserDict.DictMixin in Python 3?

Tags: dictionary, python-3.x, dictmixin

In Python 3 the `UserDict.DictMixin` class was moved to the `collections` module. The docs suggest using `collections.MutableMapping` in its place, however this abstract class does not provide a number of the methods that the `DictMixin` does/did.

Is there another (or better) way to define them short of grabbing a private copy of the `UserDict.Mixin` source for importing — or perhaps just copying the needed portions of it — into my own dictionary-like class?

Comment: Potentially helpful [article](http://python3porting.com/problems.html#replacing-userdict)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "number of methods" are specifically `__len__` and `__iter__` so the additional work is not that much.

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.mylist)

def __iter__(self):
    for i in self.mylist:
        yield i
```

Should work, I think (untested, though).

Comment: Wouldn't that `__len__` lead to infinite recursion?

Comment: @ThomasK: Yes it would, now fixed.

Comment: You're right, of course. I was misinterpreting what I saw in the docs for the [ABCs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#abcs-abstract-base-classes). For instance I wondered about all the missing `interxxx()` methods which are defined in in the Py 2.x DictMixin.py for the class...forgetting obviously that they don't exist in Py 3.x. Thanks for helping me realize my mistaken impression.

Comment: Just to clarify for those googling, are you saying these should be methods in class `UserDict(collections.MutableMapping)` ?

Comment: Note: I think this also needs `__setitem__`.

Comment: Yes, but, UserDict.DictMixin doesn't define `__setitem__` either, so your class based on DictMixin should already have them. Also true for `__delitem__` and `__getitem__`.

Comment: And with regards to your previous question: In fact, you *must* implement `__len__` and `__iter__` when you use MutableMapping. They are not optional as I thought before.