# Iterating through a dictionary of a class object without mixin - python

Tags: python, class, dictionary, iterator, mixins

The main function of the class is a dictionary with **words as keys** and **id numbers as values** (note: id is not in sequential because some of the entries are removed):

```
x = {'foo':0, 'bar':1, 'king':3}
```

When i wrote the iterator function for a `customdict` class i created, it breaks when iterating through `range(1 to infinity)` because of a KeyError.

```
class customdict():
    def __init__(self,dic):
        self.cdict = dic
        self.inverse = {}

    def keys(self): 
        # this is necessary when i try to overload the UserDict.Mixin
        return self.cdict.values()

    def __getitem__(self, valueid):
        """ Iterator function of the inversed dictionary """
        if self.inverse == {}:
            self.inverse = {v:k for k,v in self.cdict.items()}
        return self.inverse[valueid]

x = {'foo':0, 'bar':1, 'king':3}
y = customdict(x)

for i in y:
    print i
```

**Without `try and except` and accessing the `len(x)`, how could I resolve the iteration of the dictionary within the `customdict` class?**  Reason being x is >>>, len(x) will take too long for realtime.

I've tried `UserDict.DictMixin` and suddenly it works, **why is that so**?:

```
import UserDict.DictMixin
class customdict(UserDict.DictMixin):
 ...
```

**Is there a way so that i don't use Mixin because somehow in `__future__` and python3, mixins looks like it's deprecated?**

Comment: Why do you need `customedict`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165188/how-to-achieve-the-functionality-of-userdict-dictmixin-in-python-3

Comment: @thefoureye, it's part of a larger code, i just simplified the class to resolve the `__iter__()` and `__getitem__()` problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define following method.

```
def __iter__(self):
    for k in self.keys():
        yield k
```

> I've tried UserDict.DictMixin and suddenly it works, why is that so?:

Because `DictMixin` define above `__iter__` method for you.
([UserDict.py source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/UserDict.py#l95).)

Answer (score 2):

Just share another way:

```
class customdict(dict):
    def __init__(self,dic):
        dict.__init__(self,{v:k for k,v in dic.items()})        

x = {'foo':0, 'bar':1, 'king':3}
y = customdict(x)


for i in y:
    print i,y[i]
```

**result:**

```
0 foo
1 bar
3 king
```

Comment: Or for that matter, `def customdict(d): return dict((v,k) for k,v in d.items())`. That is, you don't necessarily need a class if all you're changing is the intialization.

Comment: haha,yes I agree.actually in the beginning I want to ask the OP:why not just: newdic=dict((v,k) for k,v in d.items())..it seems that all he wants is just reversed one.

Answer (score 1):

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.cdict.itervalues())
```

In Python3 you'd call `values()` instead.

You're correct that `UserDict.DictMixin` is out of date, but it's not the fact that it's a mixin that's the problem, it's the fact that `collections.Mapping` and `collections.MutableMapping` use a more sensible underlying interface. So if you want to update from `UserDict.DictMixin`, you should switch to `collections.Mapping` and implement `__iter__()` and `__len__()` instead of `keys()`.

Comment: thanks for the `__iter__()` solution, now who should i accept? both are great answers.

Comment: @alvas: they both work. The difference is that in Python 2, falstru's solution takes a copy of the values and iterates over the copy, whereas mine iterates directly over the values. This means with mine you'll get an error if you modify the dictionary while iterating over it. I consider this a feature (since it catches the user doing something they shouldn't do, they should have explicitly taken a copy), but if you *want* your class to guarantee users to be able to modify during iteration then the opposite is a feature.

Comment: @SteveJessop, There's another issue. If OP modify the `keys`, he should modify the `__iter__`. (code duplication)

Comment: @falsetru: that's true, although in Python 2 because of the copying issue, if I wanted to avoid duplication I'd do it the other way around, that is implement `keys()` as `return list(self)`. There's a *reason* `UserDict.DictMixin` is deprecated, and `collections.MutableMapping` expects `__iter__` to be defined in the derived class, which (I think) is that for some purposes `UserDict.DictMixin` over-simplifies the fundamental interface needed for a mapping.