# Python Struggling to use potara package

Tags: python, installation, package

I´m trying to use the package "potara" in python from github: 
[potara package](https://github.com/sildar/potara)

I typed

```
pip install git+git://github.com/hardymanm/potara.git
```

in cmd which works fine. Now I tried to execute the sample script

```
import potara


from summarizer import Summarizer
import document

s = Summarizer()
print("Adding docs")
s.setDocuments([document.Document('data/' + str(i) + '.txt')
       for i in range(1,10)])
print("summarizing")
s.summarize()
print(s.summary)
```

in python which gives me the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\scripts\multi_summarizer.py", line 4, in <module>
    from summarizer import Summarizer
  File "C:\Users\xxx\scripts\summarizer.py", line 22, in <module>
    import gensim
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gensim\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from gensim import utils, matutils, interfaces, corpora, models, similarities
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .dictionary import Dictionary
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\dictionary.py", line 22, in <module>
    import UserDict
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'UserDict'
```

I have no idea what the problem might be. Maybe anybody can help?

Edit:
My python version:

```
Python 3.7.0b4 (v3.7.0b4:eb96c37699, May  2 2018, 19:02:22) [MSC v.1913 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Comment: UserDict does not exist in python 3: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165188/how-to-achieve-the-functionality-of-userdict-dictmixin-in-python-3

Comment: So this means I can´t use the package until it is updated or anythin? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165188/how-to-achieve-the-functionality-of-userdict-dictmixin-in-python-3?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with this issue but you can try this (http://python3porting.com/problems.html) :

```
from collections import UserDict
from collections import MutableMapping as DictMixin

import potara
# ... etc
```